# Wordpress/WooCommerce set post/product to draft

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, visibility, hidden, status

I got a plugin for hiding a product on a particular date (called WooCommerce Limited Deals). This plugin sets the visibility of the product to hidden. What I would like to do is to set the product to Draft because if visibility is hidden, the product still shows up in search results and with direct access. Below you can find the code of the plugin that sets it to 'hidden'. Is it possible to add a line that will also set it to 'draft'?

```
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_visibility', 'hidden' );
```

For example(I know it won't work) something similar to this:

```
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'status', 'draft' );
```

Function (updated)

```
public function check_single()
{
    global $post;

    if ( $this->is_enabled( $post->id ) && !$this->is_available( $post->id ) ) {

        // Set visibility to hidden
        $hide = get_option( 'tp_hide_expired' );
        if ( $hide == 'yes' ) {
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_visibility', 'hidden' );
            wp_update_post( array(
                'ID' => $post->ID,
                    'post_status' => 'draft',
            ) );
        }

        // Remove the add to cart button
        $disable = get_option( 'tp_disable_cart' );
        if ( $disable == 'yes' ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( 'WC_Limited_Deals', 'custom_add_to_cart' ), 30 );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `wp_update_post`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

```
wp_update_post( array(
    'ID' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => 'draft',
) );
```

Comment: Tried it but didn't work. It still set the visibility to hidden, but it didn't set its status to draft. Maybe this happens because it's a woo commerce product(not sure if woo commerce products are the same with wordpress posts?).

Comment: Where are you trying to use this? Please paste a larger snippet of code. If used correctly the snippet above should work.

Comment: I need you to show me how you used the code I gave you. Please update your question including that.

Comment: Hi Nathan! I updated the code with the function as I used it.